How to summarize formulated cells in handsontable
I have here a handsontable and I'm trying to summarize the last column but the formulated cells are not added in the summary.
https://jsfiddle.net/q3b1zjcL/1/
var sourceDataObject = [
  [1, 2, "=SUM(A1:B1)"],
  [3, 4, "=SUM(A2:B2)"],
  [5, 6, 7],
  [8, 9, 10],
  [null]
],
  container = document.getElementById('example1'),
  hot;

hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: sourceDataObject,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: ['A', 'B', 'Total'],
  contextMenu: true,
  formulas: true,
  licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
  columnSummary: [
    {
      sourceColumn: 2,
      type: 'sum',
      reversedRowCoords: true,
      destinationRow: 0,
      destinationColumn: 2,
      forceNumeric: true,
    }
  ]
});


Formulated cells should also be included in summary.

Thank you for sharing the issue. Here's Aleksandra from Handsontable's Technical Support.
It seems that we weren't aware of this issue (it hasn't been reported on Github). I'll report this internally and will update this thread once the issue is solved. (If you'd like me to inform you via email, please send me a message at support@handsontable.com.)
As a temporary workaround, I'd suggest switching from columnSummary to a formula to sum up the column.
